# C# Aes Encryption IV and Key Size

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am quite new to AES Encryption and therefore have some question about IV and Key

The code I have written works, i can both encrypt and decrypt a String

Just for fun i tried to go on a Website https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption

And tried to see if the website can decrypt, if i give the same key and IV. but I ran into an error

The website said "Length of secret key should be 32 for 256 bits key size"

and "Length of initialization vector must be 16 with AES."

Is there anything I have done wrong?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 
           byte[] key = GenerateRandomByteArray(32);
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {Convert.ToBase64String(key)}");
            byte[] encrypted = EncryptMessage("test message", key);
            Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted : {Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)}");
            string decrypted = DecryptMessage(encrypted, key);
            Console.WriteLine($"Decrypted: {decrypted}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static byte[] GenerateRandomByteArray(int size)
        {
            using (RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                rng.GetBytes(buffer);
                return buffer;
            }
        }
        public static byte[] EncryptMessage(string mess, byte[] secretkey)
        {
            byte[] encrypted;
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
               
                aes.Key = secretkey;
                //Generates a IV with 16 random bytes
                aes.IV = GenerateRandomByteArray(16);

                Console.WriteLine($"IV: {Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV)}");

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Writes the IV, so when we decrypt we can get the first 16 bytes where IV i located
                            msEncrypt.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(mess);
                        }

                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;
        }

        public static string DecryptMessage(byte[] mess, byte[] key)
        {
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an Aes object
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                //Sets the AES key
                aes.Key = key;
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(mess))
                {
                    //Reads the first 16 bytes from the message which is where the IV i stored
                    byte[] iv = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];
                    msDecrypt.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);
                    //Sets the IV
                    aes.IV = iv;

                    // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

                    // Create the streams used for decryption.
                    //using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(mess))
                    //{
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return plaintext;
        }
```

Is i remember right GenerateRandomByteArray(32) is 256 bits for Key
And GenerateRandomByteArray(16) is 128 bits for IV

Output from Console:

```
Key: 3dmQoxqrAyoc5kMKQIQl8Hp4UVVCE8B64S19iNZOQRY=
IV: kO1nKUs08c/8mrlbHj3/xQ==
Encrypted : kO1nKUs08c/8mrlbHj3/xR43S5L3BJ5Ueg01xngw93I=
Decrypted: test message
```

Comment: From the example on the liked site, it does not seem that they expect the key and IV as BASE64

Comment: yea okay, even is i use this site https://www.javainuse.com/aesgenerator, it says the same error with key is more than 32 char long

Comment: What i also dont understand is if we see the IV kO1nKUs08c/8mrlbHj3/xQ== and the encrypted message kO1nKUs08c/8mrlbHj3/xR43S5L3BJ5Ueg01xngw93I=. Only a part of the IV is showing, its missing the Q==.

Comment: But the code works i can encrypt and decrypt, but i was just curious if i have done something wrong or how i actually works

Comment: The "==" is just padding and that the Q morphed into an R ist probably due to the fact that a single BASE64 character represents 6 bits and thus does not align on byte boundaries.